# Can't access non-public directories on local FS in streamsets pipeline creator

Tags: streamsets

New to streamsets. Following the documentation [tutorial](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Tutorial/BasicTutorial.html#concept_phf_cjt_ls), was getting

```
FileNotFound: ... HADOOPFS_14 ... (permission denied)
```

error when trying to set the destination location as a `local FS` directory and preview the pipeline (*basically saying either the file can't be accessed or does not exist*), yet the permissions for the directory in question are `drwxrwxr-x. 2 mapr mapr`. Eventually found workaround by setting the destination folder permissions to be publicly writable (`$chmod o+w /path/to/dir`). Yet, the user that started the `sdc` service (while I was following the installation [instructions](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Installation/FullInstall_ServiceStart.html#task_th5_1yj_dx)) should have had write permissions on that directory (was `root`).

I set the sdc [user env. vars](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/#Configuration/DCEnvironmentConfig.html#concept_rng_qym_qr). to use the name "mapr" (the owner of the directories I'm trying to access), so why did I get rejected? What is happening here when I set the env. vars. for sdc (because it does not seem to be doing anything)?

This is a snippet of what my `/opt/streamsets-datacollector/libexec/sdcd-env.sh` file looks like:

```
# user that will run the data collector, it must exist in the system
#
export SDC_USER=mapr

# group of the user that will run the data collector, it must exist in the system
#
export SDC_GROUP=mapr
```

So my question is, what determines the permissions for the `sdc` service (which I *assume* is what is being used to access FS locations by the streamsets web UI)? Any explaination or links to specific documentation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the command `ps -ef | grep sdc` to examine who the system thinks the owner of the sdc process really is, found that it was listed as:

```
sdc    36438  36216  2 09:04 ?    00:01:28 /usr/bin/java -classpath /opt/streamsets-datacollector
```

So it seems that editing `sdcd-env.sh` did not have any effect. What did work was editing the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/sdc.service` file to look like (notice that have set user and group to be the user that owns the directories to be used in the streamsets pipeline):

```
[Unit]
Description=StreamSets Data Collector (SDC)

[Service]
User=mapr
Group=mapr
LimitNOFILE=32768
Environment=SDC_CONF=/etc/sdc
Environment=SDC_HOME=/opt/streamsets-datacollector
Environment=SDC_LOG=/var/log/sdc
Environment=SDC_DATA=/var/lib/sdc
ExecStart=/opt/streamsets-datacollector/bin/streamsets dc -verbose
TimeoutSec=60
```

Then restarting the sdc service (with `systemctl start sdc`, on centos 7) showed:

```
mapr    157013 156955 83 10:38 ?    00:01:08 /usr/bin/java -classpath /opt/streamsets-datacollector...
```

and was able to validate and run pipelines with origins and destinations on local FS that are owned by the user and group set in the `sdc.service` file.

*** NOTE: the specific directories used in the initial post are hadoop-mapr directories mounted via NFS (mapr 6.0) (though the fact that they are NFS should mean that this solution should apply generally) hosted on nodes running centos 7.**